# Fwd: [Website Name] Notice of Email Change

Tags: email

I got a reply from a user today with the following email below. I have never ran into this before.  What causes this and how can it be stopped?

---

Hi username,

This notice confirms that your email was changed on website name.

If you did not change your email, please contact the Site Administrator at
admin@sitename.com

This email has been sent to username@gmail.com

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature since 4.3.0, as part of WordPress's improved security measures (check out the source on [the WordPress code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/)).

You can disable it with the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'send_email_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: That makes sense since I just updated to 4.3.  What a surpise.  Thank you so much for your help!  This works like a charm.